# Converting pairwise set on rows to columns

Tags: perl, rows

Is there a Perl solution to the following:
I have a file in the following format

```
abcdef
abcdef
abcdef
abcdef
```

This is just an example of the file the real on extends for a few thousand columns and a few hundred rows, and is made up of 1's and 0's

I want my output to be as follows

```
abababab
cdcdcdcd
efefefef
```

I've looked for answers else where and have only found solutions to transposing rows directly to columns. In this case I want to take every pair on a row and transpose them to a column.

Help would be much appreciated as I've been stuck on a solution to this for days

Comment: What about lines with differing lengths? How should the output be in that case?

Comment: Same problem answered yesterday at [PerlMonks](http://perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=1005630).

Answer (score 2):

I think my solution would use the [`Tie::File`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aFile) module to automate the buffering necessary to read through the file multiple times.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Fcntl 'O_RDONLY';
use Tie::File;
use List::Util 'max';

tie my @data, 'Tie::File', 'test.dat', mode => O_RDONLY or die $!;

my $max = max map length, @data;

for (my $index = 0; $index < $max; $index += 2) {
  print substr $_, $index, 2 for @data;
  print "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
abababab
cdcdcdcd
efefefef
```